# How to update parent Django model when child modified

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I have a simple Django model like:

```
class Parent(models.Model):

    fresh = models.BooleanField(default=True)

class Child(models.Model):

    parent = models.ForeignKey(Parent)

    <other fields>
```

I have these setup in admin so that child records show as inlines under parent:

```
class ChildInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Child

class ParentAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [ChildInline]
```

How do I configure this so that when a user creates, updates or deletes a child record, it sets `parent.fresh = False`?

I tried simply overriding the Child's save() method, but this doesn't work in admin since it saves the child first, then saves the parent record, which overwrites any modifications the child made to the parent.

I also tried setting a customer post_save signal, but the effect is the same. The signal it executed after the child is saved, but not before the parent is saved, so the changes still get overwritten.

Is there another way? Is there some post_admin_save signal?

Answer (score 0):

Exclude the `fresh` field from your admin form. The simplest way to do this is probably to set `editable=False`. Then use either a custom `save` or `post_save` signal as you've described.

There are more complicated options if for some reason you want `fresh` to be editable in the admin, but that doesn't seem terribly likely given how you're setting it.